# Fix resolution for ASUS ProArt 32" using Pop OS and Framework

Tags: xrandr, pop-os, resolution, asus

I just got a new ProArt display (32"), but unfortunately, my system only offers 2560x1440 resolution on it.

I've tried to add a new display using xrandr, however, once added, the screen doesn't display (and reverts eventually).  I'm using a USBC connection.

Commands used:

```
cvt 3840 2160 60
```

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

```
xrandr --addmode DP-4 3840x2160_60.00
```

Output of `xrandr` is then:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2256x1504     60.00 +  48.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       59.99  
   320x180       59.99  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 399mm
   2560x1440    164.85*+ 144.00   120.00    60.00  
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    25.00    24.00    23.98  
   1280x1440     59.91  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720     120.00   119.88    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98
```

Not familiar at all with xrandr, so thanks in advance for any help!